# Socket buffer binding to socket

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel, upon packet [sk_buff] receive, when is the packet bound to its socket ? i.e. when is the sk_buff's sk field populated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skb->sk` is set on receive by `skb_set_owner_r()`, for example in `net/ipv4/tcp_input.c`.  In general the networking core will dispatch packets based on ethertype to the appropriate protocol handler, and it is there that the socket is looked up and the packet put into the socket backlog for processing.